# Alternatives to the Query-string managing state

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, query-string

We're using React redux, which is fantastic. However, the moment someone refreshes their browser we lose the Redux store and as a result the application breaks or needs to redirect back to the 'start'.

We are using the Query-string to manage this, but I have been told Management this is 'Ugly' and we should find an alternate place to hold this information and remove it from the URL.

My understanding is we could use a number of things; Cookies, local storage, session storage etc.

However, I don't know which is the best to use.

We're essentially just looking for somewhere to move the information contained in the URL. E.G. https://url.com?querystring=12345&non-sensitive-id=2242

Edit: We're using Typescript, so ideally having a typesafe option would be ideal. We can achieve this with querystrings.

Comment: Redux persist exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage of HTML5.
To store data:

```js
//To store data:
        localStorage.setItem("key", 'value');
//To access data:
        localstorage.getItem("key");
//and to remove from local storage,
        localStorag.removeItem("key");
```

Comment: This is what we're using for the JWT storage, so we will probably go with this. I was just seeing if there were any we could use that were more 'Typesafe' as we're using Typescript (I'll update question to reflect this).